# доступ к переменным из метода main и другого

Tags: variable

у меня есть класс А и наследуемый от него класс В

```
public class A {
    int a = 5;    
}


class B extends A { 
}
```

Из мэйна доступ к b.a осуществляется без проблем

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        System.out.println(b.a);
    } 
}
```

но стоит int a запрятать внутрь метода - их мэйна доступ к b.a уже не удается получить - cannot find symbol

```
public class A {
    void method() {
        int a = 5;
    }
}
```

почему так просиходит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что теперь `a` это локальная переменная метода `method`, а не переменная-член класса.

Если интересно, как оно под капотом работает, то изначально, когда `a` являлась переменной-членом, то память под неё выделялась внутри объекта и мы могли обратиться к данным, лежащим в этой области памяти на протяжении жизни объекта.

Когда же она была помещена внутрь метода класса, объект стал по размеру меньше (в нашем случае наверно 1 байт*), а вот при вызове указанного метода память под локальную переменную выделяется на стеке, а после выхода (если строго, то перед выходом :)) из функции освобождается (указатель на вершину стека возвращается в прежнее положение). Соответственно данные валидны лишь во время работы функции (а если строже, то немного меньше).

---

*: в С++ был бы 1 байт, так как пустые объекты недопустимы. Здесь, я думаю, так же, но могу ошибаться.